# How to use same JQuery method for elements having different Ids?

Tags: jquery, html

**HTML FILE IS:**

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
     <script src="myjquery.js"></script>
   </head>
<a id='mylink1' href='#'>Click to Display First div</a> <br>
<div id='mydv1' style='display: none;' > I am First div</div>

<a id='mylink2' href='#'>Click to Display Second div</a> <br>
<div id='mydv2' style='display: none;' > I am Second div</div>    
</body>
```

**myjquery.js file is:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('[id^=mylink]').click(function(){
    $('[id^=mydv]').show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Actually I dont want to write two separate Jquery methods `$('#mylink1').click(function()` and `$('#mylink2').click(function()`

But using the single Jquery method like above i.e. `$('[id^=mylink]').click(function()` causes to display both divs, even by clicking on only one hyperlink.

What correction is needed in above Jquery method so that clicking on a hyperlink displays only corresponding div.

Comment: inside the handler, use $(this) to refer to the clicked element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html code

```
<input type='button' id='mylink1'/>
<div id='mydv1' style='display:none'>
I am first div
</div>
<input type='button' id='mylink2'/>
<div id='mydv2' style='display:none'>
I am second div
</div>
```

Jquery Code

```
$('[id^=mylink]').click(function(event){
     var str=event.target.id;
     var Id='#mydv'+str.slice(str.indexOf('mylink'),str.length)
     $(Id).show();
     return false;
     });
```

Fiddle Ex [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/dgjmaj8t/#&togetherjs=TtaB4EVAxp)

Comment: Works well only if mylink and mydv end with 0 or 1 or 2 or ...upto 9. Please modify str.slice(str.indexOf('vish'),str.length) portion such that it may work even for mylink and mydv ending with 0 or 1 or 2 or ...upto four digits like mylink4258 and mydv4258

Comment: Oh I found the solution. It should be str.slice(6,str.length). Now it works, no matter what length of letters are after mylink and mydv. Thnx bro

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, but should work:
HTML file

```
<html>
   <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
 <script src="myjquery.js"></script>
   </head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a id='mylink1' href='#'>Click to Display First div</a> <br>
        <div id='mydv1' class="somediv" style='display: none;' > I am First div</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a id='mylink2' href='#'>Click to Display Second div</a> <br>
        <div id='mydv2' class="somediv" style='display: none;' > I am Second div</div>   
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

JS file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.wrapper a').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.wrapper').find('.somediv').show();
        return false;
});
```